# Deserialize DateTime? Json

Tags: c#, json, datetime, serialization

I have a list which contains elements of class type which contains a property

```
[DataMember]
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

im serializing the whole list to a file like so:

```
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
    serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\json.txt"))
    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, _myList);
    }
```

and when i try to deserialize like so:

```
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\json.txt");

    _myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserInformation>>(text);
```

I'm getting the following error:

Error setting value to 'DateOfBirth' on 'Namespace'.

- EDIT -

Json Looks like: "DateOfBirth":new Date(-1459735200000) (i couldn't find how it looks when DateOfBirth == null)

I'm a beginner using Json, and im having difficulty understanding it as it is, can someone explain to me what is the problem and how do i fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the JSON look like?

Comment: Are you using wcf or a web API?  If you are serializing by hand, I would recommend the newtonsoft json serializer, and not the one packaged with WCF. (even Microsoft uses the NewtonSoft serializer for WebApi): install-package Newtonsoft.Json from nuget console -- comment back if you want more info, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: it could be related to differing datetime strings in your json. you may need to use something like newtonsoft json.net for more flexibility

Comment: snap JMarsch - my thoughts exactly

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I added the Json in edits.

Comment: @JMarsch I'm using a windows form application. I don't know what do you mean by serializing by hand, I copied the code what i use for serialization.

Comment: the -ve date is what's causing the issue here. you need to handle that in the deserialisation and take action to nullify or deal with it

Comment: Just be aware that JSON does not define a date representation, so you'll need to make sure the libraries on both ends agree on how it should be done.  See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: @jimtollan If you are using seconds since the epoch as your encoding, negative numbers are required for the many dates prior to 1970.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get an answer that helped me, I'll post what solution I've used to solve this. I didn't really want to do this but I had to change DateTime to long, and save the Ticks instead, and when i need the date i can convert like so

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(long ticks);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the newtonsoft library, then you could add a nice little generic method to `Deserialize`your json:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    try
    {
        var value =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        return value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // examine the ex.Message here if required
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

This may take you a step closer

Comment: I'm just adding the dll as refference, i dont have the whole lib in my project.

Comment: I've just added the lib, but its kind of big, where do i add this exactly?

Comment: basically, add this little method and in your client code, rem out the lines that deserialize and add instead a call to the method, using the contents of the file as the parameter, i.e `_myList = Deserialize<List<UserInformation>>(text)`

Comment: I tried this out, the only difference this is making that now it goes into the catch and it is returning null, because i don't know what to do there still, because the error message is the same, and my text file containing all the data is very huge with more then 1 DateOfBirth.